# In sharepoint list people can view only there file mentioned column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I'm new to SharePoint. I need to develop a SharePoint list that contains many files and columns. If a user is logged in, he can only view his list mentions in the field.

For example, a list contains many user details like A, B, C, D. If I enter 'A', the list shows only details of A and does not show B or C details. Is it possible using SharePoint permission?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you want to login user only can see items created by himself?

Please modify the current view, then in the filter, set Created by is equal to [Me].

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have several solutions for this.

- One of them is detailed by Emily Du - MSFT (create views).
- Another possible solution is to enable permissions at the item level, please refer: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/05/sharepoint-online-set-item-level-permission-in-list.html
- If you require something a bit more sophisticated, you can implement permissions at the item level on a list with unique permissions, controlling their access via SharePoint groups with a flow in Power Automate:

The steps would be the following:

1. An item is created (The item created has a column "user" or "group").
2. The creation action is identified in PowerAutomate, there it selects the User or SharePoint group that should have access to te specific item (the data comes from the field mentioned in step 1).
3. It's all.

Regards.

Comment: Can you explain bit more about Power Automate steps

Comment: Of course, in Power Automate you can remove item permissions inheritance, once this action is done, grant the permissions to the users/groups you want, this data must come from the item.